# Which folder should be used for common documents for all users?

Tags: windows-10, my-documents

In our software we used to store the user documents in a subfolder of CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS, which is stored in either All Users\Documents or Public\Documents (Vista and later). These documents were then visible to each user on the system from their own documents folder/library.

During testing of Windows 10 I noticed that the common documents folder is no longer visible in the users documents folder. I think this makes it hard to find the files for a casual Windows user. I didn't check this yet with Windows 8, perhaps it will have the same issue.

I'd like to know what would be the best place to store the documents that should be accessible to all the local users of the system, while keeping it easy for the users to locate the files in Windows Explorer.

Should we keep using CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS, then how can we make it easy to find? The Windows Libraries feature is hidden by default in Windows 10 and is separate from the items under 'This PC', so this doesn't seem to be a good option. We could create a shortcut in the users documents folder, but this seems like a rather messy solution because we then need to do that for all accounts on the PC.

Should we opt to just create our own folder in the C:\ root to store documents used by our application? This seems less polished to me, but at least it is easier to find for most users.

Comment: I just discovered that the Public\Desktop folder is still merged onto the users desktop. But only for the actual desktop, it does not merge in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Have you consider leaving the documents in the "correct" location and just creating a user-based shortcut that points to them?

Comment: I already mentioned that option in my question, the problem there is that we need to create that for all accounts somehow which will probably get quite messy. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Tell us a lot more about what you're trying to do... What are these documents? I can see several options that might help.    For example, using an "advertised" shortcut on the common desktop... or a small app or GPO to create the shortcuts in the user's Documents, etc.

Comment: The documents are folders containing experiment administration files and recorded data files related to laboratory equipment. We do not have control over the way the systems are managed (ie in a domain or not, user accounts, windows versions, etc). Our software install does already require administrator access, so that is okay. Basically the way it worked in Windows 7 was perfect, our installer creates a folder inside common documents that is accessible to all users and it is visible to all users. Common desktop shortcut could be a good workaround. I'll read about GPO, that might be useful.